# How will I compile and run a C program on Heroku?

Tags: c, heroku, gcc, console

As the title says, I want to run a C program on Heroku. I have been using the C buildpack by atris which can successfully compile my program and produce an executable file. However, I want to be able to *run* the program as well. I can use the Heroku console to do that, but it's tiring having to type it manually. So is there any way to run my C program automatically after compiling, on Heroku?

Comment: I mean... running code is what Heroku _does_. Is this a standalone application or part of a larger project? Are you trying to run it on a schedule? Keep it running indefinitely? Trigger it based on something? Do you need to listen for HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

Use "Procfile" in your C project to automate the execution after build.